# Running Snippet053 Jface Table Viewer troubleshoot

Tags: swt, jface, rcp, e4

This could not get weirder I was trying to run this snippet when it gives an error at following line

[StartEditorWithContextMenuu](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet053StartEditorWithContextMenu.java)

[TreeCustomMenu](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet005TreeCustomMenu.java)

```
IStructuredSelection selection = viewer.getStructuredSelection();
```

gives suggestion to change but does not help anyone knows how to resolve this issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I should trust eclipse a little more

```
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) v.getSelection();
```

resolved it looks like it is working fine but I wont know unless I completely implement it